# SQL Server - using default values

Tags: sql-server-2005

In my table there are default values set for 3 columns. I am using stored procedure on that table for creation modification and deletion.

At creation time a new row will be created with all default values set, but when I modify that row, my 3 column's default values changed as null.

How it will happened if any one know how to resolve it plz revert me as early as possible

Comment: Can you post your code and table structure?

Comment: Default values are **only** ever set at the time you **insert** a new row - they are **never** used when you update an existing row....

Comment: How would you answer the question "This is regarding SQL Server 2005"? Please let the title reflect your actual question.

Comment: BTW to all downvoters: It is a good habit to comment your downvote to let new users improve their question.

Answer (score 2):

> when i m going to do modification that time my that 3 coloumn default values changed as null

Values don't just change to NULL without a good reason. I'm guessing it's because you explicitly set them to NULL when you did your "modification". The default values only apply to inserting new rows.

If you could post more details I could give a more specific answer.